# How many monic primitive quadratic polynomials are there in $Z_{7}[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

A theorem states that "for each prime p and for each integer $n \ge 1$, there exists a monic irreducible polynomial of degree n in $Z_{p}[x]$". I am not sure if this theorem will help answer my question, but can anyone explain please?

Comment: What is a "primitive" polynomial with coefficients in a field? Do you mean monic (leading coefficient 1)?  It sounds like you're trying to kill a fly with a sledgehammer. Is this a homework question? It sure sounds like it.

Comment: A primitive polynomial is a polynomial that is irreducible and there exists a primitive element in $F_p^k$. Also your definition of a monic polynomial is correct. This is not a homework question. Can you answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $\varphi(p^n-1)$ primitive elements over $\mathbf F_p\,$ in $\,\mathbf F_{p^{\scriptstyle n}}$ and a given minimal polynomial of a  primitive element has $n$ roots, which are  also primitive elements.
Hence the number of such minimal polynomials is $$\dfrac{\varphi(p^n-1)}n.$$
In the present case,  this number is equal to:
$$\frac{\varphi(48)}2 = \frac{\varphi(2^4)\varphi(3)}2=8.$$